# Checking Removable discontinuity

Tags: continuity

Which of the following functions are not defined at $x=0$ / have removable discontinuity at the origin

> (a) $f(x) =\frac {1}{1+2^{\cot x}}$
>
> (b) $f(x) =\cos \frac {|\sin x|}{x}$
>
> (c) $f(x)  = x \sin \left(\frac\pi x\right)$
>
> (d) $f(x) = \frac{1}{\log|x|}$

According to me (a) and (d) should be the answer as it is not defined at $x=0$ but this doesn't match the answer. What is the way to check removable discontinuty

Comment: Can you write down the definition of "removable discontinuity"? Because from what you wrote, in particular "as it is not defined at x=0", you don't seem to have an understanding about what removable discontinuities are.

Comment: Well according to me removable discontunity is due to. Function not defined at a  point but we can introduce some value to make it continious.

Comment: OK. Well none of the functions are defined at $x=0$...

Comment: Every single one of these functions is not defined in $0$.

Comment: Why is (b)  and (c)  not defined at x=0.Their limits are equal.

Comment: @GENESECT (c) is not defined at $x=0$ because $\frac\pi x$ is not defined for $x=0$. Therefore, the sine of that value is not defined, because $\sin(y)$ is not defined if $y$ is defined...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Try to look at the value of $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$$

How do you think this limit is connected to removable discontinuities?

Comment: Well I think limit should exist for removable discontinuity

Comment: @GENESECT There you go. Now you have a method for solving your problem.

Comment: What can we say for function... Is it necessary for it to exist. Like (c)  the function doesn't exist but limit exists

Comment: @GENESECT The limit at $0$ exists, but the function is not defined at $0$ if and only if the function has a removable discontinuity at $0$.